# SQL server join vs subquery performance question

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I discovered that in some cases a query like

```
select 
   usertable.userid,
   (select top 1 name from nametable where userid = usertable.userid) as name 
from usertable 
where active = 1
```

takes an order of magnitude longer to complete in SS2008R2 than the equivalent join query

```
select 
   usertable.userid,
   nametable.name 
from usertable 
left join nametable on nametable.userid = usertable.userid 
where usertable.active = 1
```

where both tables are indexed and have over 100k rows.  Interestingly, inserting a top clause into the original query makes it perform on par with the join query:

```
select 
    top (select count(*) from usertable where active = 1) usertable.userid,
    (select top 1 name from nametable where userid = usertable.userid) as name 
from usertable 
where active = 1
```

Does anyone have any idea why the original query performs so poorly?

Comment: FYI when diagnosing performance problems you should always get a query execution plan.

Comment: If you have access to Safari Books Online have a look at "Inside Microsoft® SQL Server 2005: Query Tuning and Optimization - chapter 3" Or Another  good link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/09/27/774107.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the queries are different - unless the `userid` column is a primary key or has a uniqueness constraint then the second query could return more rows than the first.

That said, with the assumption that userid is a primary key / unique try removing the `TOP 1` part of the first subquery:

```
select 
   usertable.userid,
   (select name from nametable where userid = usertable.userid) as name 
from usertable 
where active = 1
```

Comment: That totally did the trick.  I had it in there as a precaution to avoid runtime errors since the query is generated on the fly.  Now I need to figure out if I can safely remove it as a general rule.

Answer (score 2):

It's a correlated subquery, which means it needs to execute once per return row of the outer query since it references a field in the outer query.

A `JOIN` runs once for the entire result set and gets merged.  Your subquery runs the outer query, then for each returned row it runs the subquery again.

Comment: I don't think this is true with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

The original query will execute the sub `select` as many times as there are rows, thus the poor performance.

When you `JOIN` you get the whole result set at once.